# Detect iOS8 power/wake button - private apis

Tags: ios8, iphone-privateapi, guided-access

I've been trying to use private-apis to detect when the user pressed the power/wake button without success.

My investigation has led me to GSEvent 
(http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/GSEvent)

However this api is no longer available on iOS 8 
(https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework)

Has anyone had any luck detecting button events on iOS 8

Please note: I am not interested in using the UIApplicationDelegate, only detecting button presses